# How to Close Network Scan Search Screen Programatically in Intent Service(Android)

Tags: android, android-intent, intentservice, activity-finish

Actually I'm developing an Application to programmatically searching the network scan in android. So that I am using the below code to search programmatically in Intent Service,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        intent.setClassName("com.android.phone",
                "com.android.phone.NetworkSetting");
        startActivity(intent);
```

So searching network scan is working properly, but my intention is to close the screen which is opened "Com.android.phone.Network Setting" in Intent service.

Please help me to close the opened Intent after some duration or scan gets completed.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You have no control over other applications. You can start them, but you cannot stop them.